# How to define a networkx subgraph only based on out_edges?

Tags: networkx

I would like to get a subgraph around a specific node of a a directed graph based on the out_edges or in_edges only.

```
# This does not work
H_tmp = nx.ego_graph(G, node_name, 2)
H_tmp.out_edges = []
H = nx.ego_graph(H_tmp, node_name, 2)
```

I tried using `nx.ego_graph` twice, but I don't know an efficient way to remove all the out_edges or in_edges. Is there a way to tell `ego_graph` to use only a specific set of edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `eco_graph` function on an undirected graph extracts the out successors of the node. According to the [doc](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.ego.ego_graph.html), if you only want the predecessors (in_edges), you can apply the `eco_graph` function on the reverse of your graph. You'll then need to reverse your subgraph. If you want both successors and predecessors, you can specify `undirected=True`. See example summarizing this below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(5, 0.3,directed=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

plt.subplot(141)
plt.title('Full graph')
nx.draw(H,with_labels=True)

plt.subplot(142)
plt.title('All neighbors around node 2')
H_all=nx.ego_graph(H, 2, 1,undirected=True)
nx.draw(H_all,with_labels=True)#plot

plt.subplot(143)
plt.title('Out subgraph around node 2')
H_out=nx.ego_graph(H, 2, 1)
nx.draw(H_out,with_labels=True) #plot

plt.subplot(144)
plt.title('In subgraph around node 2')
H_in=nx.ego_graph(H.reverse(), 2, 1) #apply eco_graph to reverse graph to get in_edges
H_in_r=H_in.reverse() #reverse subgraph 
nx.draw(H_in_r,with_labels=True) #plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is a great comprehensive answer!